# Listview update image after getView()

Tags: android, listview, listener

I'm writing an app that shows images in a listview after downloading them from the internet.  If an image has not downloaded when `getView()` is called, I have a placeholder image.  The problem with this is if `getView()` is called before the image is downloaded, and the user does not scroll anymore, the placeholder image will stay there until the user scrolls away and comes back to call `getView()` on that position again.

I'm looking for a way to listen for the file being created and when it is, update that row.  Is this possible?  I've googled around, but cannot seem to find anything.  I would imagine I would have to call an `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`, but I don't know how to listen for a file being created.

Comment: Take a look at "lazy loading images" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview

Comment: The example here: https://github.com/thest1/LazyList has all of the code you need